# How do I setup a bluetooth dongle in my Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, usb, bluetooth

I recently bought a USB dongle for Bluetooth. It worked on my Windows 10 but in ubuntu, it is not showing anything. I tried using Blueman but my device headsets keep disconnecting in 5-6 mins. Please Help Me

Thanks in Advance :)